# How to change order of elements in a row from horizontal to vertical?

Tags: css

How I can change the order of elements using CSS. I cannot edit its HTML.

The **quantity box** is in line with add to cart button. I want it to appear it above **Add to cart**.

Live URL: https://mytimios.ml/baby-0-2-years/

[image]

Result i want to achieve using CSS:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using:

```
.astra-shop-summary-wrap {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}
```

This also works:

```
.qib-container {
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   width:100%;
   margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
```

I'm not sure why `display:block` does not work, but adding a with to it works as it is set to `inline-block`.

Comment: @AnjlyShines Please see my answer, i edited it. `it's set to display:inline-block so should be on its own line anyway` - thats not true. `display: inline-block` makes the element behave like a block element, but does not put it on a line of its own.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant that you can give it a width to take up the space though. I tried `display:block` on it for OP too and can confirm that does not work. I'm not sure what's interfering with it. Giving the element a width works though as it already has `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your css:

```css
div.qib-container {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I did but nothing happened. Please check.

Comment: @AnjlyShines see my answer please. i edited it.